# <Missing LoadingScreenManager.LoadScene> even though it's not?

Tags: unity, windows, scene

What was once a smooth loading screen, is now a frozen screen. From my main menu, it usually skips the loading screen and dives into the gameplay (which isn't too bad) but the real issue, is if you're in the help menu and chose 'Play' from there.

It'll load into the loading screen, then freeze.

From the inspector under the slider, it shows:
[image: On Value Changes (Single)]

Now, I have the loading Screen Manager and it's script set up, so I'm not sure why it's doing this. What I would like to do is to get it working again, whether I stick to sceneBuildIndex or go by sceneName but the problem here, when I try either one, it doesn't seem to have any real changes at all.

Here is a copy of the full script from a tutorial I followed when I was just starting out:

```
// LoadingScreenManager
// --------------------------------
// built by Martin Nerurkar (http://www.martin.nerurkar.de)
// for Nowhere Prophet (http://www.noprophet.com)
//
// Licensed under GNU General Public License v3.0
// http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoadingScreenManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    [Header("Loading Visuals")]
    public Image loadingIcon;
    public Image loadingDoneIcon;
    public Text loadingText;
    public Image progressBar;
    public Image fadeOverlay;

    [Header("Timing Settings")]
    public float waitOnLoadEnd = 0.25f;
    public float fadeDuration = 0.25f;

    [Header("Loading Settings")]
    public LoadSceneMode loadSceneMode = LoadSceneMode.Single;
    public ThreadPriority loadThreadPriority;

    [Header("Other")]
    // If loading additive, link to the cameras audio listener, to avoid multiple active audio listeners
    public AudioListener audioListener;

    AsyncOperation operation;
    Scene currentScene;

    public static int sceneToLoad = -1;

    // IMPORTANT! This is the build index of your loading scene. You need to change this to match your actual scene index
    private static int loadingSceneIndex = 4;

    public static void LoadScene(int levelNum)
    {
        Application.backgroundLoadingPriority = ThreadPriority.High;
        sceneToLoad = levelNum;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(loadingSceneIndex);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        if (sceneToLoad < 0)
            return;

        fadeOverlay.gameObject.SetActive(true); // Making sure it's on so that we can crossfade Alpha
        currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
        StartCoroutine(LoadAsync(sceneToLoad));
    }

    private IEnumerator LoadAsync(int levelNum)
    {
        ShowLoadingVisuals();

        yield return null;

        FadeIn();
        StartOperation(levelNum);

        float lastProgress = 0f;

        // operation does not auto-activate scene, so it's stuck at 0.9
        while (DoneLoading() == false)
        {
            yield return null;

            if (Mathf.Approximately(operation.progress, lastProgress) == false)
            {
                progressBar.fillAmount = operation.progress;
                lastProgress = operation.progress;
            }
        }

        if (loadSceneMode == LoadSceneMode.Additive)
            audioListener.enabled = false;

        ShowCompletionVisuals();

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitOnLoadEnd);

        FadeOut();

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(fadeDuration);

        if (loadSceneMode == LoadSceneMode.Additive)
            SceneManager.UnloadScene(currentScene.name);
        else
            operation.allowSceneActivation = true;
    }

    private void StartOperation(int levelNum)
    {
        Application.backgroundLoadingPriority = loadThreadPriority;
        operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(levelNum, loadSceneMode);


        if (loadSceneMode == LoadSceneMode.Single)
            operation.allowSceneActivation = false;
    }

    private bool DoneLoading()
    {
        return (loadSceneMode == LoadSceneMode.Additive && operation.isDone) || (loadSceneMode == LoadSceneMode.Single && operation.progress >= 0.9f);
    }

    void FadeIn()
    {
        fadeOverlay.CrossFadeAlpha(0, fadeDuration, true);
    }

    void FadeOut()
    {
        fadeOverlay.CrossFadeAlpha(1, fadeDuration, true);
    }

    void ShowLoadingVisuals()
    {
        loadingIcon.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        loadingDoneIcon.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        progressBar.fillAmount = 0f;
        loadingText.text = "LOADING...";
    }

    void ShowCompletionVisuals()
    {
        loadingIcon.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        loadingDoneIcon.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        progressBar.fillAmount = 1f;
        loadingText.text = "LOADING DONE";
    }

}
```

I'm reading the manual here, but I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding it, or if there's an error in the script:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

Comment: My first instinct says the problem is the method is static. Try removing the word “static” before “void LoadScene”

Comment: @EdMarty that looks to me like a good candidate for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a lot going on in your question here, but if I’m understanding correctly, the problem you want solved is just that the On Value Changes event can’t find the LoadScene method on LoadingScreenManager.

If that’s the case, my guess is that the problem is that the method is static. Try changing

```
public static void LoadScene
```

To this

```
public void LoadScene
```

And see if it can find it now.